# I want to summon a mob that has an item as passenger

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen the same question, with an example that said `/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Item",Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b}}]}`.
But this doesn't work. Probably because commands have changed, but is there a new way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I was just trying tings and got `/summon zombie ~5 ~ ~5 {Passengers:[{id:item,Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b}}]}`
I don't know what the difference is but I'm glad I found out

Comment: The difference is in `id:"Item",` and `id:item`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was id:Item (There is no id:"minecraft:Item" the is though a "minecraft:item")

it looks like when you switch the ID that might have fixed your issue (Also the words minecraft: are uneeded but used just in case you have other datapacks with custom items)